# Can I clone someone else's heroku app into my Heroku account?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli, heroku-api

Can I clone someone else's heroku app into my Heroku account?
if yes please give some hint/Doc

Comment: Is the person who owns the app willing to let you?

Comment: he is not active in any social media

Comment: Is the source code published somewhere, and licensed such that you're allowed to use it?

Comment: @Chris yes i have

Comment: "yes i have"... what? You have made contact with the owner of the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer applications between Heroku accounts or to a team of which you are a member at any time via the [Heroku Dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/) or the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) command apps:transfer.

> Billing responsibility will transfer to the new owner as of the time
> of accepting the transfer and the original owner will be responsible
> for pro-rated usage up until that point. After the transfer is
> complete, the original owner will be a collaborator on the app.

**To initiate the transfer of the application using the CLI, use apps:transfer:**

```
heroku apps:transfer -a <app-to-transfer> <collaborator-to-transfer-it-to@example.com>
```

If you need to transfer multiple apps, use the --bulk flag:

```
heroku apps:transfer --bulk <collaborator-to-transfer-it-to@example.com>
```

**To initiate the transfer of the application using the Dashboard:**

1. In Dashboard, click the **`Settings`** tab of the application.
2. Scroll down to the **`Transfer Ownership`** section.
3. Click the **`Select a new owner`** field. The list of people who are collaborators on the app and the list of Teams and Organizations to which you belong will be displayed.
4. If you don’t see the person you want to transfer the app to, then you must first [add them as a collaborator](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/collaborating#add-collaborators). If you can’t see the team that you want to transfer the app to, then you must [ask the team admin to add you to the team](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/develop-orgs#joining-an-enterprise-team).
5. Select an item from the list.
6. Click **`Transfer`**.

Comment: sorry to say i'm not the owner of app, app owner is not active in social media.

i want clone this app in my account, i want add some things in appp

app link:  https://github.com/voshawn/sessionize-cafe